# Get user data collected by Google tag manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-tag-manager

I have a Ruby-on-Rails web application with implemented google tag manager (GTM). Assume, that some user comes to my site, surfs several pages and then sends me a feedback through feedback form. Is there any way to gather as much data as possible which is collected by GTM for current user session in order to send it together with this feedback?

Comment: GTM does not collect data. It is possible to implement Javascript Tags in GTM that collect user data and send it somewhere else (it might be impractical or illegal, but is certainly possible). You need to be more specific to get an answer and boil it down to a question about implementation to make  this on-topic. As it stands this is too broad.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff, I'll make it more specific

Comment: I tried to make my question more concrete. It can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585302/how-to-get-user-surfing-statistics